# Voice calls in Slack Desktop stopped working

Tags: slack

I'm curious if someone still can make voice calls from Slack's desktop client from Ubuntu 14.04? And if so **what did you do to make them working?**
Although, voice call from the same machine via Chromium is working.

It was okay before

```
slack --version
2.5.1

lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```