# Slack calls do not connect

Tags: 16.04, slack

My Slack calls do not work. I can conduct the call and the "connecting" pop up simply stays as connecting and my partner never connects with me (i.e. the circle progress animation never stops spinning). This is the same regardless of whether I make the call or she makes the call. And unlike [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/900067/voice-calls-in-slack-desktop-stopped-working) unanswered question with the same issue, the issue persists even on Chromium.

```
slack --version
2.8.1

lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

Comment: what output do you get if you run slack from the terminal and make a call?

Comment: Hope this doesn't seem too ignorant, but how do I run Slack from the terminal? If I type in 'slack' the slack desktop app opens but then there's no output stream for whatever I do in Slack so it doesn't "run from the terminal". It opens as a separate process.